# Python "generic" class property encode/decode

Tags: python

I almost guarantee this is something simple.  I am trying to create a generic property to wrap a django text/blob field.  This isn't Django specific, its really just an issue with design.  I have some class level variables and am using a pseudo delegate to be able to reuse an decode method.

```
class DBTable(models.Model):
  class Meta:
     db_table="some_table"

  def set_data(self, data):
     att = self.__getattribute__(data.__name__)
     att = base64.encodestring(data)

  def get_data(self,prop):
     def func(self):
         att = self.__getattribute__(prop)
         return base64.decodestring(att)
     return func

  #issue is here, i need to pass self to get_data
  blob_a = property(get_data("blob_a"), set_data)
  blob_b = property(get_data('blob_b'), set_data)
```

And the issue comes on the above two lines, I need to pass self.  I have tried using the class but its not recognized.

---

It was simple, the problem above was fixed by pulling it out, and below is the final working solution.

```
def encode_data(self, data):
     def func(self,data):
        self.__setattr__(prop, base64.encodestring(data))
     return func

def decode_data(self,prop):
     def func(self):
         att = self.__getattribute__(prop)
         return base64.decodestring(att)
     return func


class DBTable(models.Model):
  class Meta:
     db_table="some_table"

  blob_a = property(decode_data("_blob_a"), encode_data("_blob_a"))
  blob_b = property(decode_data('_blob_b'), encode_data("_blob_b"))

  _blob_a = models.TextField(
        db_column='blob_a',
        blank=True)
  _blob_b = models.TextField(
        db_column='blob_b',
        blank=True)
```

Comment: In your final solution, how is `get_data` and `set_data` defined?

Comment: I had a typo, i renamed them to encode/decode.  However its not final yet bc i am in an infinite loop, its basically recursively calling setattr.  Working on that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove `self` from `get_data` and make it a function outside the class.

`get_data_factory("blob_a")` will return a function, which expects `self` as an argument. That is perfectly fine. It does not have to receive (in fact, it should not receive) that value from `get_data`.

```
def get_data_factory(prop):
    def get_data(self):
        return base64.decodestring(getattr(self,prop))
    return get_data

class DBTable(models.Model):
    ...
    blob_a = property(get_data_factory("blob_a"), set_data)
```

---

Regarding the final solution: I think there is a problem with the call signature of `encode_data` and `decode_data`. Perhaps you meant:

```
def encode_data(prop):
     def func(self,data):
        setattr(self,prop, base64.encodestring(data))
     return func

def decode_data(prop):
     def func(self):
         return base64.decodestring(getattr(self,prop))
     return func
```

Comment: Do I just need to ignore the "warning" about needing self as first parameter?  Is there a less smelly annoation besides ignore?

Comment: @Nix: Could you show the warning? I'm not sure why you should get one.

Comment: I had the warning bc i left the get_data inside the class.

Comment: @Nix: I don't think it is possible to define it inside the class definition, because you can't call methods, staticmethods, or classmethods *before* the class definition is completed. You either have to move the `get_data_factory` outside the class definition, or else move the `blob_a = property(...)` statement outside the class definition.

Comment: Technically you could leave it in the class definition and it would still work.  ;) it just wreaks of bad code, and is is ugly in the ide, I moved it up and made it more generic by naming it encode/decode.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Nix: Oops, you are correct -- you can define a plain function inside the class, and call it to define a class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use `def get_data(prop):` - only your inner function should accept `self` as the outer one is not executed as an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with lambda:

```
blob_a = property(lambda s: s.get_data('blob_a'), lambda s: s.set_data('blob_a'))
blob_b = property(lambda s: s.get_data('blob_b'), lambda s: s.set_data('blob_b'))
```